# What is the reverse of PHP function POW('base','exponent')?

Tags: php, logging, pow

I have gone through number of searches to find the solution to fine exponent or power of a value if we have base value and final value.

Community helped each other a lot but didn't gave an answer which is already PHP is having and is very simple.

*The reason i am posting this **question and its answer both** - to help the community with this simple answer.*

Comment: *"but didn't gave an answer"* Since you posted the same answer you posted here, under another question who's answer already mentioned `log`, that is not true.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the Answer ---**

```
pow(3,4) it will generate 81
Reverse is
log(81,3)  it will generate 4
```